How to make mappings for "jump to after next occurrence of character" / "jump to the before previous occurrence of character"?
There are standard keybindings:
fx - jump to next occurrence of character x
tx - jump to before next occurrence of character x
Fx - jump to the previous occurrence of character x
Tx - jump to after previous occurrence of character x

How to make mapping for jump to after next occurrence of character: fx l (find next character and go one char right)? And what shortcut better to select that will not affect main out of the box bindings like i, r, a, f, t, m, v and so on?
Also it will be good to consider corresponding reverse operation: jump to the before previous occurrence of character x Fx h (find previous char and go one char left).
I have the following mapping from here:
" dil to delete inside line, yil would yank the line, cil to change and so on
onoremap il :<c-u>normal! $v0<cr>

Probably configuration for the current question will be similar to it? Is this possible?
Probably this question will be duplicate of related question:
Jumping to one character past the search. But here I want to clarify some additional details since accepted answer in the related question does not suit me.

To jump to the character after you could do:
nnoremap <expr> <C-f> 'f'.nr2char(getchar()).'l'

To jump before the character you could do:
nnoremap <expr> <C-S-f> 'F'.nr2char(getchar()).'h'

About the mapping nearly all the keys are already mapped (see this answer for reference).
You can choose:

<leader> mapping (e.g. <leader>f equivalent by default to \f unless you change the value of <leader>)
A double key mapping (you have more room but not too much see @romainl page).


This is great, thanks! Here post with description that Ctrl and Ctrl + Shift cannot be distinguished by terminal and Vim. How do you setup them? If I put in config both this mappings no one is working. With binding the seconds shortcut as nnoremap <expr> <C-t> 'F'.nr2char(getchar()).'h' both are working.

This depends indeed of the version of Vim you are using and the terminal your using :-/ Maybe you can use Alt mappings that are free (<A-f>)

After typing <leader>fx I probably might as well type fxl  (not a critique of the answer, which is good; jw what motivated the question).

With the help of this and this posts I was able to map Alt+f by nnoremap <expr> <Esc>f 'F'.nr2char(getchar()).'h' (find in left direction) mapping for Ubuntu terminal

What terminal do you use that distinguishes Ctrl + Shift from Ctrl?

My mistake :-| I have tested on Windows and Vim 9.1 and it seems it can make the distinction (I thought the problem was solved :-|)
